binary image surface coverage calculation yields inconsistent results despite correct visual appearance
I’m working with a binary image generated from a microscopy image where I’m trying to calculate the surface coverage of stack-like structures (cells). The image visually shows these structures correctly, but my pixel counts for the surface coverage calculation don’t match what I see.
Here's a breakdown of my problem:

The image is binary (0s and 1s), with one value representing the stack areas (cells) and the other representing the background.

When I view the binary image, the cells appear correctly segmented. However, when I calculate the surface coverage by counting the relevant pixels (either 0s or 1s), the result is consistently lower than expected.


What I Tried:

I verified the binary image by inspecting unique values and using histogram analysis. The image histogram shows two peaks, close to 0 and 255, which suggests that the image is indeed binary.
I attempted adaptive thresholding, global thresholding, and hole-filling, but these methods yielded either incorrect pixel counts or failed to improve the coverage accuracy.
Directly counting pixels with the intensity representing the stacks (e.g., 0s or 255s) gives a lower-than-expected percentage.

Question: Why might a binary image with visually correct segmentation produce inaccurate surface coverage when counting pixels, and how can I ensure my pixel counts align with the visual appearance?
Here’s a code snippet that I’m using to calculate surface coverage:
def calculate_surface_coverage(binary_image, stack_value=0):
    stack_pixel_count = np.sum(binary_image == stack_value)
    total_pixels = binary_image.size
    surface_coverage = (stack_pixel_count / total_pixels) * 100
    return surface_coverage
    
surface_coverage = calculate_surface_coverage(binary_image, stack_value=0)
print(f"Surface Coverage: {surface_coverage:.2f}%")


[mre] required. data required. explain your expectation, qualitatively and quantitatively. and please don't emulate ChatGPT's writing/formatting style, nor let it write your question.

If your result is different from the expected value, then most likely your expected value is wrong. It is also possible that binary_image is a 3D array, and you're only looking at one slice, giving you a skewed perception of the fraction of set pixels.

The image histogram shows two peaks, close to 0 and 255, which suggests that the image is indeed binary.  Close to 0 and 255?  Should be right on 0 and 255, and only on those values.  How are you binarizing?
